# problems with a regular expression

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to get a correct regular expression for this problem:

I get a result from a webservice as a string that looks like this

> tag: 54e16e66 (Mifare card standard)

I need to extract the **54e16e66** part (which is in hexa) only, regardless of what is before and after that part, i've tried several patterns, but I am not confident enough with regex and I can't seem to find a pattern that works.

**Edit**

- "tag :" is aways present.
- the hexa part I want to extract has variable length
- what is after is a user comment, so it could be anything

Could someone help ? thanks in advance !
Michael

Comment: you can't parse that without givin us more information. your hexa part has to be between some start and end pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string there is a good template, and assuming a posix regular expression parser,

```
/^tag: ([0-9a-f]{8})/
```

should work. If the length is variable, you would just change the `{8}` to `{m,n}`, where `m` and `n` are the minimum and maximum possible number of characters you can expect, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what if the length of the part is variable?

Comment: @Themikebe `([0-9a-f]{8})` -> `([0-9a-f]+)` assuming a greedy matcher. (Edit: Oh, the answer was edited in the meantime.)

Comment: @them - answer updated. If you're really completely unfamiliar with regex, definitely read up a bit on it before just implementing something some guy on SO told you; they're ridonkulously useful, but they can be a real bear to work with sometimes.